# Updating toggle buttons check state when one of them is toggled

Tags: c#, wpf, infragistics

I have a XamDataGrid with 2 fields. In the second field, I have toggle buttons. When the `ToggleButton` is clicked, the value gets set correctly. But at any time user should be able to check only one `ToggleButton` among all the records. The data in the set logic for the Default property works fine. But I need to set the values of Default for other items in DataSource.

Using a `RadioButton` instead of `ToggleButton` would the ideal solution. But it is possible that none of the records are default. So I want a solution to make the other default fields false when one of them becomes true.

XAML for field:

```
<igWPF:Field Name="Default" Width="84">
    <igWPF:Field.Settings>
        <igWPF:FieldSettings CellValuePresenterStyle="{StaticResource ButtonDefault}" />
    </igWPF:Field.Settings>
</igWPF:Field>
```

XAML for CellValuePresenterStyle:

```
<Style x:Key="ButtonDefault" TargetType="{x:Type igWPF:CellValuePresenter}" >
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type igWPF:CellValuePresenter}">
                <ToggleButton Content="Default" 
                              HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                              VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                              FontSize="16" 
                              Width="80" 
                              Height="36"
                              IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Datasource:

```
public class LanguageSettingItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;

    private bool isDefault;

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set { this.name = value; PropChanged("Name"); }
    }
    public bool Default 
    {
        get { return this.isDefault; }
        set { this.isDefault= value; PropChanged("Default"); }
    }

    public void PropChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have Toggle Button event Checked and Unchecked with same event Handler. 
Then just put a if condition - (if toggle_btn.isChecked)'checked code' else 'unchecked code'

Comment: I tried this. But no clue why it doesn't trigger for unchecked.